# Create common codable for slightly different json responses - Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

How to create a common codable struct in swift for slightly different json responses.For example `response A` and `B` has almost same attributes and `B` has some extra attribute called `Designation`.Is it possible to create common codable struct for this scenario?

```
//Response A
{
  "name" : "Jhon",
  "age" : 23,
  "mobile" : "+11012341234",
  .
  .
  .
}

//Response B
{
  "name" : "Jhon",
  "age" : 23,
  "mobile" : "+11012341234",
  .
  .
  .
  "designation": "Manager"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optionals like so:

```
struct Response: Decodable {

   var name: String
   var age: Int
   var mobile: String
   var designation: String?

   // If you need to decode, it would look like this:
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
      age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
      mobile = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .mobile)

      // Decode designation if provided
      if container.contains(.designation){
         designation = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .designation)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You won't even need a custom initialiser by the way.

Comment: @Patru For such a simple structure, no. I commented "If you need to decode" because if needed for other additional variables (to decode strings to integers, for instance), OP will know to use `if container.contains(.key)` for optional keys